# forwarding MailItem Outlook Addinn issue

Tags: c#, email, outlook

i am trying to get the selected mail item on the click of a button and then i have to forward it to some fixed email adress ,i m very new to c# language,this is the function which i m using with my mailitem to forward

```
          private void sendMail(MailItem mail)
          {
             mail.to = "myemailid@gmail.com"; //my fixed email adress 
             mail.cc="";   //removing any carboncopy users
             mail.bcc=""; //removing any blind carbon copy users
             mail.send();
           }
```

this is working correctly but what happens is as i forward the email it is in my sentbox with to:myemailid@gmail.com,but it gets deleted from my inbox. i thought that it might be due the same instance of mail item i m using,so i tried using this code

```
                private void sendMail(MailItem mail)
                {MailItem newmail = mail;
                 newmail.to = "myemailid@gmail.com"; //my fixed email adress
                 newmail.cc="";   //removing any carboncopy users
                 newmail.bcc=""; //removing any blind carbon copy users

                 //++ some code for coping the attachments ++

                  newmail.send();
                 }
```

but this is also resulting in same situation..it gets forwarded but gets deleted from my inbox

Answer (score 7):

I got my answer,anyway if someone other need this can use this :-)

```
             private void sendMail(MailItem mail)
             {MailItem newmail = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;

             newmail = mail.Forward();
             newmail.Recipients.Add("myemailid@gmail.com");
             newmail.Send();
             }
```