# How to Forward Current Message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook utility to forward the currently open message to a preset address.

This could be done with a macro but they are not as easily deployed to a user base.

I have created the UI for the add-in through Visual Studio ribbon design. I have a button on the ribbon to use for this process.

I am trying to put in button action similar to what is described here: [forwarding MailItem Outlook Addinn issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385619/forwarding-mailitem-outlook-addinn-issue?newreg=97d6721bc550416b9e2785e294a3aa28).

How can I forward the current selection?

```
namespace OutlookAddIn2
{
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        sendMail();
    }
    private void sendMail(Outlook.MailItem mail)
    {

        Outlook.Application Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Outlook.MailItem newmail =     Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
        newmail = mail.Forward();
        newmail.Recipients.Add("____@example.com");
        newmail.Send();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance if you develop an add-in. Instead, you need to use the Application property which is available everywhere. See [Global Access to Objects in Office Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhczd18c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

In case if you deal with inspector windows you can use the following sequence of calls:

```
 Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem
```

where the [ActiveInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which returns the topmost Inspector object on the desktop. Use this method to access the Inspector object that the user is most likely to be viewing. For example:

```
Sub CloseItem() 
  Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
  Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
  Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem 
  myItem.Close olSave 
End Sub
```

But if you need to get the currently selected item in the Explorer window you can use the following sequence:

```
Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]
```

where the [ActiveExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870017.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method returns the topmost Explorer object on the desktop. This method is also useful for determining when there is no active explorer, so a new one can be opened.

Comment: How do I add that to "sendMail()"??  I'm also confused about how the code from the link uses a parameter with no definition of input type

Answer (score 0):

The above code CloseItem() executed within an excel workbook rendered a run-time error 438, Object does not support this property or method. The reason I suspect is that there is no correct reference to the Outlook object model created.

I found a solution in code published by Wedge: [Edit an open email from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596796/edit-an-open-email-from-excel)

I implemented the solution for the same purpose as above.

The adjusted code is as follows:

```
Sub CloseItemEdit()

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim outlookInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outlookInspector = outlookApp.ActiveInspector

If Not outlookInspector Is Nothing Then
    If TypeOf outlookInspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set outlookMail = outlookInspector.CurrentItem

    outlookMail.Close olSave

    End If

End If

'Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596796/edit-an-open-email-from-excel

End Sub
```