# Edit an open email from excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Edit: Thank you everyone. All the suggestions probably work. I just finally realized, there's a security option enabled by my employer to prevent this type of action. Unfortunately, I can't edit emails, only create them.

I'm trying to figure out how to modify an open email from excel.

I have an email template that excel will replace certain strings with values from a worksheet in my workbook.

I've been researching **activeinspector**, but I'm still unsure how cross programming works between excel and outlook. Searching various sites gets me this, but it's not working.

> Error 287 on str = outlookMail.Body

```
' Create the outlook object
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim outlookInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set outlookInspector = outlookApp.ActiveInspector

Dim str As String

If Not outlookInspector Is Nothing Then
    If TypeOf outlookInspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set outlookMail = outlookInspector.CurrentItem
        str = outlookMail.Body

        ' Replacements
        str = Replace(str, "DIPOC", "string1")
        str = Replace(str, "REFNUM", "string2")
        str = Replace(str, "RCVDATE", "string3")
        str = Replace(str, "EMPNAME", "string4")
        str = Replace(str, "EMPEIDN", "string5")
        str = Replace(str, "ACTIONREQ", "string6")

        outlookMail.Body = str
    End If
End If
```

I'm still new to this so any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know how relevant this is, but way back when in Excel V4 (no laughing.. :) ) we used APP.ACTIVATE, EXECUTE, and SEND.KEYS to run other programs. The one I set up entered data that took ages to do by hand, as it was single data piece and wait for the server response... So just an idea, but it still seems to be around : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys

Comment: @SolarMike nowadays you just reference the other application's object model, and poof you have access to every object in the type library, just like you were in Outlook.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sounds simple then, but why doesn't it work...

Comment: @SolarMike most likely I'm just referencing it wrong somehow. It's a common thing with me. ^_^'

Comment: It will come, have a break, have a KitKat or coffee...

Comment: Check if my answer to another post helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217576/3266371

Answer (score 1):

This will fail if there isn't an active e-mail open (there's no error handling code here), but just for testing purposes it was functioning for me. I am assuming dipoc, RefNum, rcvdate are variables you have defined elsewhere (I tested it with static strings). Also the name of the Outlook object is "Outlook", so it would be best to avoid naming an object "Outlook". If you have HTML formatting in an e-mail (like in a signature), you want to use .HTMLBody instead of .Body

```
Sub test()
    ' Create the outlook object
    Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olInspector As Object
    Dim olOutMail As Object
    Set olInspector = olApp.ActiveInspector
    Set olOutMail = olInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim str As String
    str = olOutMail.Body

    ' Replacements
    str = Replace(str, "DIPOC", dipoc)
    str = Replace(str, "REFNUM", RefNum)
    str = Replace(str, "RCVDATE", rcvdate)

    olOutMail.Body = str

    ' Remove the outlook objects
    Set olInspector = Nothing
    Set olOutMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Dim Outlook As Object
> Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
>
> Dim oInspector As Inspector
> Dim olOutMail As MailItem
> ```

If your code compiles, then you have a reference to the Outlook object model, and the `Outlook` identifier refers to the `Outlook` type library: `Dim Outlook As Object` is *shadowing* that declaration. Rename it, and explicitly qualify the types with the library they're from:

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim outlookInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
```

I couldn't figure out a consistent scheme for your prefixing, so I dropped it.

Now when you assign the inspector reference:

> ```
> Set oInspector = Outlook.ActiveInspector
> ```

That's ambiguous, at least to a human reader: if you get *IntelliSense* when you type that `.` dot, then VBA is understanding `Outlook` as `Outlook.Application`, and this means trouble, for now you have an implicit `Application` reference *that is not the instance you mean to work with*... and that could very well why you're getting this error.

You want to disambiguate that.

```
Set outlookInspector = outlookApp.ActiveInspector
```

That should give you the `Inspector` reference you mean to work with.

Next problem, is that you set the `olOutMail` object reference *assuming* there's an active inspector, and that you're looking at a `MailItem` - expect fire if either assumption isn't true.

```
If Not outlookInspector Is Nothing Then
    If TypeOf outlookInspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        'NOW we KNOW we're looking at a mailitem.
        Set outlookMail = outlookInspector.CurrentItem
        '...work with outlookMail here...
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it. The object model is starting to make sense. I removed the ambiguity and used your naming scheme. It looks better and logical. With an open email in forced plaintext mode, it has a plaintext signature containing the message and all the strings to be replaced. I'm still getting error 287 on str = outlookMail.Body. (I updated the code in the original post). I've even tried outlookMail.HTMLBody as suggested elsewhere.

Thank you for all you help <3

Comment: Ok. I added outlookMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain, and it is indeed, affecting the mail. It changed HTML to plaintext and vice versa. The code just does not like storing the body text into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the olOutMail variable before you initialize the oInspector variable.
Switch them around:

```
Set oInspector = Outlook.ActiveInspector
Set olOutMail = oInspector.CurrentItem
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually had it correct in the source, but when I was copying it over, omitting unnecessary bits, it got switched around. Still getting the error 287

Answer (score 0):

it runs well from my end. It changes my email to plain text format.

Here is my test environment: Office 2016 + windows 10 and below are the code I’ve tested.

```
Sub strat()
' Create the outlook object
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim outlookInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outlookInspector = outlookApp.ActiveInspector
Dim str As String
If Not outlookInspector Is Nothing Then
    If TypeOf outlookInspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set outlookMail = outlookInspector.CurrentItem
        str = outlookMail.Body

        ' Replacements
        str = Replace(str, "For", "string1")
        str = Replace(str, "REFNUM", "string2")
        str = Replace(str, "RCVDATE", "string3")
        str = Replace(str, "EMPNAME", "string4")
        str = Replace(str, "EMPEIDN", "string5")
        str = Replace(str, "ACTIONREQ", "string6")
        outlookMail.Body = str
        MsgBox str
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Best Regards,

Evan